# Installing of email composer cordova plugin error

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

## Error when run in command promopt

When I run cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-email-composer@0.8.3 in my command prompt, I get this error and the plugin is installed into my phonegap plugins folder.

> Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-email-composer':Error: cmd: Command
>   failed with exit code ENOENT
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
>   ordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:202:12)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:577:11)
>       at run (node.js:348:7)
>       at startup (node.js:140:9) Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

How do I solve this error and what is causing this error?

Comment: Are you able to build the project into cmd without any error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search the error of `Command failed with exit code ENOENT` then generally it is because of a old version of either plugin or cordova itself

I am using version 6.2.0 ( c:>cordova -v ) of cordova

`This plugin is installed successfully into my app`

So what actually you have to do is to **update your cordova**, below is a process of upgrading your cordova

**In a Windows environment:**

If you have already installed cordova, then follow the steps:

1) npm uninstall -g cordova
2) Delete folder C:\Users\your-name.cordova
3) Into Environment Variables...
4) Define C:\Windows\System32 as a System Variable(Bottom Window) ie SYSTEM_HOME
5) Then define %SYSTEM_HOME% in the Server Variables (Top Window)
6) Then run npm install -g cordova
7) Now go to the project folder and try again: cordova platform add android

Hope this will help you

Comment: May be the problem is because of your system variable path, please share your path links from system variable so I can check and if there is any wrong order of path causing this problem.

Comment: put the platform-tools last and tools second last into your system path variable

Comment: great, can you please let us know what was the problem and hows you solve it.

Comment: i forgot to add apache into system path